# Force HTTPS & Non-WWW for a subdomain dynamically

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to work out a .htaccess rule that I can use on my main domain & subdomains without requiring changes to the code for each one.

I've tried the following for a subdomain to try and force https and non-www but it doesn't work correctly.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Force HTTPS & NON-WWW
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.website\.com$ [NC] # Detect if it has www?
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on  [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test\.website\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://test\.website\.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Currently if I was to go to `http://www.test.website.com/test/` it redirects to `https://test%2Cwebsite.com/` so it sort of works but not quite.

I've been trying to do it more dynamically too using:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on  [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But this isn't working at all. What's the best solution to achieve this?

It should essentially be forcing all of the following:

```
http://website.com/                   => https://website.com/
http://www.website.com/               => https://website.com/
https://www.website.com/              => https://website.com/

http://website.com/testing/           => https://website.com/testing/
http://www.website.com/testing/       => https://website.com/testing/
https://www.website.com/testing/      => https://website.com/testing/

http://test.website.com/              => https://test.website.com/
http://www.test.website.com/          => https://test.website.com/
https://www.test.website.com/         => https://test.website.com/

http://test.website.com/testing/      => https://test.website.com/testing/
http://www.test.website.com/testing/  => https://test.website.com/testing/
https://www.test.website.com/testing/ => https://test.website.com/testing/
```

Comment: "it redirects to `https://test%2Cwebsite.com/`" - There's something strange going on there, it doesn't relate to the directives you posted above. `%2C` is an encoded comma?! Where is that coming from?

Comment: @w3dk I too couldn't understand the %2C, there's no comma in the url yet it is putting one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this single dynamic rule to achieve all `http -> https` and `www -> non-www` redirections:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure this rule is right at top and you clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Is the 3rd `RewriteCond` directive necessary? Providing you reorder the first two and include the capturing group on, what was the first rule: `^www\.(.+)`?

Comment: @w3dk Yes it is necessary for capturing the part after optional `www`. The 2 conditions, before are using `OR` clause hence only one will be executed and we cannot capture anything from them.

Comment: It works perfectly in my initial tests, only 1 rewrite rule which is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```bsh
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    # First, force the HTTPS, whatever it is:
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Then drop the www, if any:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
    RewriteRule .* https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
## Results:
# http://website.com/      => https://website.com/
# http://www.website.com/  => https://website.com/
# https://www.website.com/ => https://website.com/

# http://website.com/testing/      => https://website.com/testing/
# http://www.website.com/testing/  => https://website.com/testing/
# https://www.website.com/testing/ => https://website.com/testing/

# http://test.website.com/      => https://test.website.com/
# http://www.test.website.com/  => https://test.website.com/
# https://www.test.website.com/ => https://test.website.com/

# http://test.website.com/testing/      => https://test.website.com/testing/
# http://www.test.website.com/testing/  => https://test.website.com/testing/
# https://www.test.website.com/testing/ => https://test.website.com/testing/
```

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite rule must be (in the first example):

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://test.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Remove the backslashes, as the rewrite goal is no regex.

For your overall solution, I guess you need two seperate rewrites. One to do the https check and the other to remove the www. I guess it will not be possible in one rewrite, because you need to check two conditions, of which only one might match.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on  [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```